# php file from command line using ant - windows

Tags: php, ant

I'm trying to run an ant script which is set to execute various php modules e.g.

```
<target name="phploc" description="Measure project size using PHPLOC">
  <exec executable="${basedir}/build/tools/phploc.phar">
   <arg value="--count-tests" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/tests" />
  </exec>
 </target>
```

However it's failing with the error "%1 is not a valid Win32 application"

I've performed the registry tweaks as described here...
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

and also repeated them for phar.  If I open a command window I can execute a php or phar file just by typing it's name e.g. phploc.phar  rather than the full php.exe phploc.phar however it's not working via ant.

If I change ant file to:

```
 <target name="phploc" description="Measure project size using PHPLOC">
  <exec executable="php">
   <arg line="${basedir}/build/tools/phploc.phar --count-tests" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/tests" />
  </exec>
 </target>
```

everything works fine as I guess that's translated to `php.exe /build/tools/phploc.phar` (or something like that).

The build file is from someone else's project which i've cloned via git so ideally I don't want to have to change it.

So I guess I don't understand why it's working via the commandline (i.e. recognising that .php .phar are executable) but not via ant. What's the difference?

Thanks!

NB: I have php installed standalone (no apache) on a windows machine being using as a build server (jenkins).  PATH has been changed to include php dir.

Answer (score 1):

Windows *.bat files have to be run thorugh the `cmd`. Change your example to:

```
<target name="phploc" description="Measure project size using PHPLOC">
    <exec executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="${basedir}/build/tools/phploc"/>
        <arg value="--count-tests" />
        <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
        <arg path="${basedir}/tests" />
    </exec>
</target>
```